# In PowerBI how do I fetch the most recent data from my database with my Python script?

Tags: python, powerbi

I'm new to PowerBI and so far I've been able to create a function that sends a request to my local database and retrieves a record that is then converted to a dataframe. Only problem is that every time I run it it keeps returning the same data. It's only when I create a new function and run it the first time does it get the most recent data. Here is the PowerBI query:

```
= () => let
        Source = Python.Execute("import requests#(lf)
import pandas as pd#(lf)import json#(lf)#(lf)def get_modifier(supplier=None, date=None):#(lf)    print(""SUPPLIER"", supplier)#(lf)    headers = {#(lf)        ""Content-Type"": ""application/json""#(lf)    }#(lf)#(lf)    data = {#(lf)        
""query"": '''query getOneModi($supplier:String, $date:String){#(lf)  modifier(supplier:$supplier, date:$date){#(lf)    modifier#(lf)    supplier#(lf)    date#(lf)    }#(lf)    }''',#(lf)#(lf)    ""variables"": {""supplier"": supplier}#(lf)    }
#(lf)#(lf)    data = json.dumps(data)#(lf)    response = requests.post(""http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql/"", headers=headers, data=data)#(lf)    info = response.text#(lf)    info = json.loads(info)#(lf)    # print(""MODI RESPONSE"", info, ""\n"")#(lf)#(lf)    #(lf)    
return info[""data""][""modifier""][0][""modifier""]#(lf)#(lf)data = get_modifier(""Esso"")#(lf)data = json.loads(data)#(lf)d = {""Moncton"": data[""Moncton""], ""Sherbrooke"": data[""Sherbrooke""], ""Julie"":data[""Julie""]}#(lf)modi_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0])#(lf)print(modi_df)"),
                        Custom1 = Source,
                        modi_df1 = Custom1{[Name="modi_df"]}[Value],
                        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(modi_df1,{{"Moncton", type text}})
                    in
                        #"Changed Type"
```

I don't think the problem is with the Power Query itself, rather I'm just unfamiliar with the PowerBI features. How do I get the function to run a new query every time rather than return old data, is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have not gotten data using Python in the past using Power BI but whenever I encounter issues with Data not Refreshing I check the Data Cache Management Options by going to:
File > Options and Settings > Options > Data Load > Clear Cache.

Check the options and see if there is a way not to cache your result set. Hopefully, this will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't realize there was a manual refresh button. I clicked that and it worked, I tried going to "Data Load" but there's no "Clear cache" option

Comment: Some data connection types may not have clear cache or that option especially live connections but worth to check if Power BI caching something. It got me a few times especially when you change the database columns in the backend and then Power BI did not seem to refresh anything.

Comment: @Dmitra K hey sorry the late reply, thank you again for the suggestions I'll have a look some more

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I just pressed "refresh all" in the Home tab and it ran the function again and returned the most recent data.